# Gh + Jekyll + LAMP for authentication?

Tags: php, html, github, jekyll, lamp

I've spent the entire morning scouring the internet trying to find a solution to this and I haven't found one yet so now I'm here. I have a LAMP server on digital ocean and I want to use it strictly as a database server. I have a Jekyll site on Github that I've got up and running, but I want to know if there is a way to send users over to my LAMP server for authentication, but use my Jekyll site for the rest of the website. Would it be possible to redirect the page to the server and then have the root directory of the virtual host in the url location? I want to implement this all on the same domain, but I want to do it this way to make it fast and efficient.

Would I have to use different two nameservers from different domains and would this cause any problems?

I know you can do a Jekyll-Angular-Firebase stack, but I want something that I can maintain on my own and don't have to pay $50 a month for.

Would it be possible to talk to the database in the form itself so that everything else is static and doesn't have to be processed by the lamp server?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks you.

Comment: I wonder: what do you need database for?
Authentication looks like something impossible to do on static web. Event using multiple nameservers, still, you cannot verify anything on the static web.

Also, if you know and prefer PHP, I'd recommend using Sculpin.

Comment: I want authentication so that I can host multiple eCommerce sites. I did find a way to host a jekyll server inside of  LAMP, but then I have to install Ruby and I don't really want to do that. I'm thinking about getting an open-source BaaS and trying to find out how to integrate it so I can make my own.

Answer (score 1):

Just deploy/upload your static site (the '_site' folder in Jekyll) to your LAMP stack and add some php files for authentication.

Comment: I was thinking about doing that, but not sure just yet how to go about it. Thanks for the reply though :).